# Linq - Unexpected uniqueness constraint-type behaviour occurring

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, sql-server-2008, xtragrid

I have a database with a simple flyweight table referenced by another table. Let's call them, respectively, Category and Product.

The Product table has several columns, one of which is a foreign key column (complete with constraint) to the CategoryID to a row of the Category table. It's simple, and I have many of them in this particular database.

I am using Linq in Visual Studio 2008 to represent this data in my application. Both tables appear as normal, and neither have anything special in their properties that would indicate the behaviour I'll describe.

In the database itself, there are several Product rows which have `CategoryID=1`. There are two or three that have `CategoryID=2`. However, when the data is loaded into my application through Linq, iterating through `context.Products` shows that the first three have `CategoryID=1`, `CategoryID=2` and `CategoryID=3`, and all the rest of the rows have `CategoryID=NULL`. This is not how it appears in the database. There are no other anomalies in this database.

Help?

edit: I've posted an answer below, but maybe the DevExpress guys can chime in? I'm happy it's now working correctly but I'm not happy that I still don't understand what went wrong.

Comment: What does the generated SQL look like?

Comment: @JonSkeet `SELECT [t0].ProductID, [t0].Description, [t0].CategoryID FROM dbo.Product AS [t0]` - nothing unusual. The collection returned by the Debug Visualiser has all the correct data, but when I iterate through it (or set it as the DataSource of a grid), it suddenly becomes incorrect.

Comment: It seems unlikely that that would give the wrong data... how are you diagnosing that the data is wrong in your application? Have you tried a small console app which just fetches the data and prints it out? (If so, can you post that app?)

Comment: As soon as I iterate through the collection and print out the `CategoryID` of each, it shows up incorrectly. The generated objects are also behaving oddly - when set as the DataSource of a grid, changing the `CategoryID` of one of them (to, say, ID=3) causes the object with CategoryID = 3 to switch to `NULL`! Seriously weird behaviour.

Comment: Are your types autogenerated, or did you write them yourselves? I wonder whether you've got two properties hooked up to the same field, or something like that...

Comment: By types, are you meaning varchar, int, etc? They are just simple int and varchar values. Is there any way for me to find out if there are two properties sharing a field? (I am using partial classes, but not for either of the classes in question)

Comment: No, I mean your entity type. You would find out if two properties share a field by looking at the code... but it will very much depend on whether they're autogenerated or not.

Comment: They are autogenerated. I'll try checking the autogenerated code for weirdness.

Comment: Nothing that I can see, but I'm not really used to digging around in the autogenerated code.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the auto-generated code to be wrong. I can understand how binding things in a grid could have odd effects, but a simple console app just displaying results should be okay...

Comment: Answer below... or at least, how I got it to stop doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here was twofold:

1. I regenerated the entire database in the dbml file. This fixed the incorrect data showing up when I iterated through the query, but the data was still coming up incorrectly when I tried to put that data in the grid.
2. I had created a new column before doing step 1, and the data was showing up incorrectly. After doing step 1, the data in this new column (mapped only to `CategoryID`) was showing up correctly. However, the data in the original column (mapped to the entity `Category`) was still behaving as originally described. Once I changed the field from `Category` to `CategoryID` the behaviour stopped. I'm still not sure exactly why that happened, but at least for now I have a fix.

Thanks for your help, @JonSkeet. :)